# Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a sheet called "Dashboard" that I have several charts on, but every week I'm adding data to the tables these charts are based on. The second sheet that has the data for this table is "Historical Totals" and the data I want is in columns A through E (this includes labels and headers). I'm trying to automate the charts updating, and I don't quite know why this isn't working. Here is the code I have so far:

`Sheets("Dashboard").Select

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Activate

ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Historical Totals").Range("A1", Range("E1").End(xlDown))`

I've tried seperating our the range, and it is selecting the appropriate data, so I don't really know where I'm making the mistake.

Comment: Call `Sheets("Dashboard").Activate` as well before starting.

Comment: So I added that comment, and it still gave the same error. Wouldn't calling `Sheets("Dashboard").Select` do the same thing as that though?

Comment: which version of XL are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the following. You need to reference the data sheet every time you use Range:

```
Sheets("Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 4").Activate
ActiveChart.SetSourceData _
        Source:=Sheets("Historical Totals").Range(Sheets("Historical Totals").Range("A1"), _
                Sheets("Historical Totals").Range("E1").End(xlDown))
```

Comment: Thanks! This didn't quite do it for me- gave me the "object doesn't support this property or method" error, but I just called for the chart to activate, and then did the `SetSourceData` with `ActiveChart`. Worked like a charm with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have the table in the `worksheet` "Historical Totals" I would usually go `xlUp` rather than `xlDown` but the following is effectively the same as Philip A Barnes's answer:

```
Sub setArea()

With Excel.ActiveWorkbook
        '.Sheets("Dashboard").Select '<==no need to select for the code to execute
        .Sheets("Dashboard").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
End With

With Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Historical Totals")
     Excel.ActiveChart.SetSourceData _
                      Source:=.Range( _
                                    .Cells(1, 1), _
                                    .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(Excel.xlUp).Row, 5) _
                                    )
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The problem with the `xlUp` is that I don't know the size of the table at any given time. It grows every week, so I'm trying to make it dynamic in determining the size of the data by checking what information is actually there.

Comment: ...hmmm doesn't sound like you have tested my code: or understand what it does. It effectively goes from the last row in the sheet (row 1,048,576 in my version of XL) and then up to the next row with data in it !! So no problem if your data grows from 50 rows to 70 rows it will always find the last row of data!! The advantage of using `xlUp` is that if you have 50 rows of data but `E30` is blank and then try to use `xldown` from `E1` then it will definitely not find `E50`